# How to clear BLE Advertisement data in esp32

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, esp32

I want to clear my esp32 BLE advertisement to default after setting Ibeacon data to it beacause i want to set its advertisement for eddystone URL.

```
//Here i want to clear previously assigned advertisment data
padvertisment->start();
startbeacon();
padvertisment->stop();
```

I have explored a lot but I have not found anything regarding this.

Comment: Are you using ibeacon together with eddystone in the same project?

Comment: Yes i want to change Ibeacon advertisement data to URL and TLM and vice versa, actually i am trying to make multiple beacons by writing values through characteristics . But when shift from ibeacon to URL or URL to beacon it is showing merge data of both on nrf connect app. While shifting from ibeacon to TLM and TLM to URL is going as expected.

Comment: I see. This could also be a simple caching error on the reading device. Please connect to the device while the merged data is visible and select "Refresh serices" in the upper right menu. If you are disconnected you can try selecting "refresh device cache"

Comment: No after refreshing services the problem is same. I am looking to clear previously assigned beacon data before calling next beacon advertising data function.

Comment: Could you add some more code to your question or list the libraries you are using? You can [edit] your question to add the info